# Fixing hinge on a screen door

Tags: doors

The screen door hit the jam this morning and taking a look I see the lower hinge has pulled out. It's held into the aluminium frame using what appear to be sheet metal screws, and I don't think there's anything behind them on the door side. Here's an image, I'm not sure it's very clear:

[image]

If you can make that out, you can see the hinge has pulled away. You'll also note that the current location of the screws is not the originals, so this happened in the past and the previous owner simply made new holes in the middle of the hinge.

I don't think putting another set of screws in another set of holes is the solution, does anyone have other suggestions? Is there some sort of tiny toggle bolt that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's because they've loosened/pulled out, the next step might be to go with larger diameter screws.  Drill the holes out bigger, replace with bigger screws for more bite.

Comment: Ok I guess that makes sense. I worry there is no end to that process though. I will try it though.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Your worry is founded, because it's correct.  At some point, you will find the meat of that door edge so destroyed that replacing it will be the only option.  On a normal door, I'd also suggest moving the hinge up/down, but with this type of door, that isn't an option.